# What is this font

Tags: font-identification

I've tried everywhere to find the name of that font (What the font, identifont, etc...), it is a font i KNOW, i had, but can't remember the name...! it's close to Code Pro, but the R closes, the I and the S are very identifiable, but the name's not coming back! Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: it does look like a cheap version of Galano Grotesque Alt... but it's not that...!

Comment: Is it from some webpage? It can be extractable.

Comment: The image is too low resolution to get a match in whatthefont, and other similar sites. Don't you have a higher resolution sample?

Comment: hi all, thanks!
it's from a building signage. I'll try to get a better photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest: [Brasley Semi Bold](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/nicolas-desle/brasley) via fontspring.com.

[image: brasley]